# How to open an external url in new tab using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 10 application in which I make an API call and the get an external URL to download a `pdf file`. How do I open the URL in a new tab.
`window.open(url)` works perfectly but is there any alternative to using the window object?

Comment: I think using the window object is the only way, Maybe you could create an element with target blank and click it from code, but that would just be silly.

Comment: "is there any alternative to using the window object?" — What is wrong with using the window object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you add `target="_blank"` to the anchor (or button)

```
<a target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/link'] OR href">
    Open in New Window
</a>
```

But I wonder what's the problem of using window.open? I think it just perfect for this situation

Another approach is calling the file from service, then blob it, then no need to open new window, is that work for you case?

```
  public export(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`url/export`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

Then

```
public export(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.export().pipe(tap(data => downloadAsCSVFile(data, 'test')));
  }


const downloadAsCSVFile = (csv: string, fileName: string): void => {
  const blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
  saveAs(blob, `${fileName}.csv`);
};
```

Maybe you can try

Comment: thanks for your help. window object can cause issues with SSR so I wanted to avoid it. Also my url is an external website so not sure if [routerLink]="['/link'] will work

Comment: then you can use [href] binding, however I think the underlying of those are still window.open()

You can even create service and then call HTTP request for downloading, then can avoid open new window? how about it

Comment: update the answer, you still need to update a bit but I think you can try it @Yogesh